# ODataClient: Executing DataServiceActionQueries in a batch

Tags: c#, odata, microsoft-odata

I'm migrating from SimpleOdataClient to MS ODataClient and I wonder how to execute DataServiceActionQueries in a batch. Executing DataServiceRequests in a batch is not a problem, but I haven't found a solution for DataServiceActionQueries. Is it possible?

Comment: What is the difference between DataServiceRequests and DataServiceActionQueries?  You can put the query into a request.

Comment: The client code generator of OData Connected Services generates a Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceActionQuery for my unbound actions. How can I put this into a request? I think I'm too stupid right now

Comment: The query is public DataServiceActionQuery (Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext context, string requestUriString, params Microsoft.OData.Client.BodyOperationParameter[] parameters);  So  you just need to send the object in the request.  For example the context is a set of classes so you can serialize the classes (binary serialize or xml serialize) and send in the body of a request.  You just have to define your own protocol for send and receiving the objects.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I will try this.
But of course this is far from being convenient...